Charge full subscription amount in first subscription in stripe
I have set the billing_cycle_anchor and to the 1st date of every month.
And when the customer makes subscription then the stripe is automatically calculating prorated amount and charging that amount.
Is there any way that I charge the full amount in first subscription while including billing_cycle_anchor also?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
